# Error in create Trigger with heidi sql 1064

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this following code:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER t_autoinsert AFTER INSERT
  ON originalattlog
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT scan_date FROM triggerattlog WHERE scan_date = NEW.scan_date) THEN
    INSERT INTO triggerattlog (att_id,sn,scan_date,pin,verify_mode,io_mode,work_code,ex_id,flag,rowguid,io_mode_update,TIMESTAMPinfo)
    VALUES (NEW.att_id, NEW.sn, NEW.scan_date, NEW.pin, NEW.verify_mode, NEW.io_mode, NEW.work_code, NEW.ex_id, NEW.flag, NEW.rowguid, NEW.io_mode_update, NEW.TIMESTAMPinfo);
  END IF;
END
```

I have that code and it gets error (1064) my SQL. I use `heidisql`.

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: Probably, you are just missing the `delimiter` specification here.

Comment: Convert this trigger code to single-statement form (`INSERT .. SELECT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS (..)`) which does not need in BEGIN-END and DELIMITER.